# How to subset a PredictionClust/Prediction/R6 object

Tags: r, mlr3

I have a clustering task with about 500k datapoints. I want to plot the clusters but my machine can't handle an `autoplot()` with that amount of data. What are the alternatives?

Is it possible to plot only the contours or maybe subset the prediction object for plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use the `row_ids` argument of `autoplot()`? You can plot a subset of your predictions with it. This could still fail with large data but maybe it is works on your machine.

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3cluster)
library(mlr3viz)

task = mlr_tasks$get("usarrests")
learner = mlr_learners$get("clust.kmeans")
learner$train(task)
preds = learner$predict(task = task)

row_ids = sample(preds$row_ids, 10)
autoplot(preds, task, row_ids = row_ids)
```